# python regex parsing xml, save the results to the dictionary. Like the following

Tags: python, xml, regex

```
<manifest>
    <item href="Text/Briefcontent.xhtml" id="Briefcontent.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
    <item href="Text/Section115.xhtml" id="Section115.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
 </manifest>
```

I need results like this: `key=id, value=href`

```
dict={'Briefcontent.xhtml':'Text/Briefcontent.xhtml', 'Section115.xhtml':'Text/Section115.xhtml'}
```

What should I write python code？

Comment: -1 : don't agree with the inital upvote. The question does not show research effort. There are a ton of questions on `regex` and `xml`, so I doubt it's is more useful than the others. It is clear in simply asking for a piece of code.

Comment: don't agree with your "a ton of.....". I use the example above, in order to be more intuitive. As for the 'more useful', depends on how you answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.crummy.com%2Fsoftware%2FBeautifulSoup%2F&ei=V9-tUeH7Isq3iQe9sIDwDg&usg=AFQjCNHAxwplurFOBqg5cehWQEVKi-TuLQ&sig2=XTa5vQksXZlgGMjygtHA3Q&bvm=bv.47244034,d.aGc):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> xml = """<manifest>
...     <item href="Text/Briefcontent.xhtml" id="Briefcontent.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
...     <item href="Text/Section115.xhtml" id="Section115.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml" />
...  </manifest>"""
>>> soup = BS(xml, 'xml')
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in soup.findAll('item'):
...     idict = i.attrs
...     d[idict['id']] = idict['href']
>>> d
{u'Briefcontent.xhtml': u'Text/Briefcontent.xhtml', u'Section115.xhtml': u'Text/Section115.xhtml'}
```